# HTML Django conditional statement dependent on radio button choices

Tags: html, django, if-statement

I am working on an attendance system where teachers can mark a student as Present, Absent, or Late, but they can only enter a comment if a student is marked Absent or Late. I would like to make the Comment text input `disabled` when Present is selected. I tried different if statements with `<input type="text" name='{{student.ssystudentid}}_comment' id="comment" maxlength="100">`, but none seemed to work. Below is my code and a screenshot of the page.

```
<form action="{% url 'attendance:submitAttendance' %}" method="post" name="fullForm">
                {% csrf_token %}

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Student Name</th>
                        <th>P/A/L</th>
                        <th>Comment</th>
                    </tr>
                    {% for student in list_of_students %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{student}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="radio-button">
                                    {% for attendanceType in list_of_attendanceTypes %}
                                        {% if attendanceType.attendancetype == "Present" %}    
                                            <input type="radio" name='{{student.ssystudentid}}_attendancetype' id='{{student.ssystudentid}}{{attendanceType}}' value={{attendanceType.attendancetypeid}} checked="checked">
                                            <label for='{{student.ssystudentid}}{{attendanceType}}'> {{attendanceType}}</label>
                                        {% else %}
                                            <input type="radio" name='{{student.ssystudentid}}_attendancetype' id='{{student.ssystudentid}}{{attendanceType}}' value={{attendanceType.attendancetypeid}}>
                                            <label for='{{student.ssystudentid}}{{attendanceType}}'> {{attendanceType}}</label>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                    <input type="text" name='{{student.ssystudentid}}_comment' id="comment" maxlength="100">

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>
                <input type = "submit" value = "Save Attendance"/>
                </form>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Please note that I am not using Django forms.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use django template language conditions to check the radio button choice of the user. To achieve what you want, you need javascript and have the comment field hidden by default, and shown on selection of the attendance field.

It might look something like;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    toggleFields(); // call this first so we start out with the correct visibility depending on the selected form values
    // this will call our toggleFields function every time the selection value of the attendance type field changes
    $(".attendancetype-class").change(function () {
        toggleFields();
    });

});
// this toggles the visibility of comment
function toggleFields() {
    if ($(".attendancetype-class").checked)
        $("#comment").show();
    else
        $("#comment").hide();
}
```

Though bare in mind that you're setting the "Present" radio button by default, so the comment field will always be visible because the radio button is selected by default. You'll also need some kind of selector that allows you to get any of the radio buttons in Javascript. So maybe a class?

I would also recommend using a django form for this. This brings lots of benefits, but specifically here it'll allow you to run validation to ensure that the attendance field is completed if a comment is provided.

It's also worth noting that it's good practice to keep templates as simple as possible and avoid logic in templates. This comes to mind when I see that `for` loop with the `if/else` in it. Though the check on attendance type seems to be for the default check (you can avoid all this by using a django form). If you create this iterable in your view and you know the first item is "Present" you can then check it like this;

```
{% for attendanceType in list_of_attendanceTypes %}
    <input type="radio" name='{{student.ssystudentid}}_attendancetype'
           id='{{student.ssystudentid}}{{attendanceType}}'
           value={{attendanceType.attendancetypeid}}
           {% if forloop.first %}checked="checked"{% endif %}>
```

Docs for the `for` template tag [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

Comment: Thank you. Right now, my company decided not to use Django forms, but perhaps we will rethink that decision. What is the best way to implement the Javascript solution that you are referring to?

Comment: I added some simple javascript. But then realised you're checking one of the radio buttons by default, so the comment field will always be visible.

Comment: Got it. I'm new to Django, so this question is pretty basic...where do I put that code? In the static directory and then link it to the template? Or something totally different?

Comment: Yeah it depends a bit on how you have things configured, but typically you'd have a javascript file in your static directory and you can load that in your template using the `static` template tag. Reading this may help; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/